# Jetpack Compose : How to move up the floatingActionButton for snackbar?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button, android-snackbar, compose-desktop

I am trying to make the floating action button move up to make room for the Snackbar to appear, which is the
normal behavior when using android xml UI files.

It looks like its not implemented in Scafford.

Please find below my code so far on Compose for desktop (But it should be similar on Android) :

```
fun main() = Window(
    title = "Box Demo",
    size = IntSize(600, 500)
) {

    MaterialTheme {

        val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

        val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

        Scaffold(
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,

            snackbarHost = {scaffoldState.snackbarHostState },

            floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,

            floatingActionButton = { FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) { Text("+") } },

            topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("TopAppBar") }) },

            bottomBar = { BottomAppBar() { Text("BottomAppBar") } }

        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp, start = 20.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        GlobalScope.launch {
                            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                message = "Hey I am a snackbar",
                                actionLabel = "Hide",
                                duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                            )
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Show snackbar")
                }

                SnackbarHost(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 180.dp),
                    hostState = snackbarHostState,
                    snackbar = {
                        Snackbar(
                            action = {
                                TextButton(
                                    onClick = {
                                        snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()
                                    }
                                ) {
                                    Text(
                                        text = snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.actionLabel ?: "",
                                        style = TextStyle(color = Color.White)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.message ?: "")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my config:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "0.2.0-build132"
}
```

Comment: You could use the ``Modifier::offset`` function and move it up manually, based on a state.

Comment: @u2gilles come up with a solution?

Comment: Hello, u2gilles.  Did you find a solution? I'm facing same issue now and found your question here on Stack

Answer (score 7):

I was asking the same question in the slack channel of compose (kotlinlang.slack.com, https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1627831971210600).

Here is the answer of Ian Lak, a Google employee:

> This is specifically one of the "Don't" examples from the Material guidelines: https://material.io/components/snackbars#behavior
>
> Making sure visual elements don't move out from underneath (say, when users are about to tap the FAB) is one of the key points to making a predictable UI

(slightly modified as there were some wording issues)

Comment: I don't want to follow the guideline because of the feature in app. Is there no other way other than Guidelines?

Comment: Well you can of course build a custom implementation