# Jetpack compose show Snackbar below FAB

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

- I have displayed a snackbar with `Floating Action Button` but `Snackbar` shows up above the `FAB` and it want it show it below the `FAB`.
- As per the guidelines snackbar must be above FAB but in the app as per the funtionality I have to display it below.
- I also tried with `Modifier.offset()` but Snackbar is sticked with FAB offset.
- There is a simliar question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672644/jetpack-compose-how-to-move-up-the-floatingactionbutton-for-snackbar) but that doesn't answer the question.

Here is some snippet of my code:

```
@Composable
fun snackBarDemo() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val snackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(drawerState, snackbarHostState)

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        drawerContent = {},
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Hello this is my snackbar")
                    }
                }) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp, top = 2.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    ) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Updated the question with code snippet @GabrieleMariotti